# Ionic unit testing alertcontroller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine

I am working for an application that uses an alert to tell the user it is using nfc. I am unit testing this app and put a spy on the alertcontroller.create method as follows:

```
alertController.create = jasmine.createSpy().and.resolveTo({
    present: jasmine.createSpy()
});
```

In the unit test I want to check if it is called with the right alert options as follows:

```
      expect(alertController.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        header: 'NFC aan het lezen...',
        message: 'Hou de pas tegen de achterkant van de telefoon',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Anuleren',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => nfc.stopRead()
          }
        ]
      });
```

The problem however is that it gives an error while running the test because of the handler. How can I effectively test if the alertcontroller.create function is called with the correct values? As right now the test gives the following error:

```
  Expected $[0].buttons[0].handler = Function to equal Function.
```

I want to check if the provided object is correct but the function doesn't check.

Comment: what is `nfc` ?

Comment: @KiranMistry nfc is the class that controls my reading of nfc cards, it has a method stopRead that unsubsribes from the listener so it will only read when the pop up is there.

Comment: ok...so `nfc.stopRead()` function not calling right if not calling then try with this `{ nfc.stopRead() }`

Comment: @KiranMistry for the execution of this test it doesn't matter if it is called or not. the problem is in the unit test to expect the handler to be the same as in the actual code. This is only my unit test, it should see if the alertController create function was called with the provided value.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with

```
jasmine.any(Function)
```

So the code is as follows:

```
      expect(alertController.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        header: 'NFC aan het lezen...',
        message: 'Hou de pas tegen de achterkant van de telefoon',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Anuleren',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: jasmine.any(Function) as any
          }
        ]
      });
```